# Merge and output selected data in SAS

Tags: merge, window, sas, subquery, output

I am trying to merge and output some dataset in SAS. The idea is very simple,

My data looks like:

Data1 (Target Data)

```
RIC       date           
VOD     03/02/2014         
BATS    03/02/2014         
...       ...
```

Data2(Sample Data)

```
RIC       date           price
VOD     01/02/2014         50
VOD     03/02/2014         57
VOD     05/02/2014         64
VOD     06/02/2014         58
VOD     08/02/2014         64
VOD     10/02/2014         57
...       ...             ...
BATS    01/02/2014         70
BATS    03/02/2014         58
BATS    05/02/2014         67
BATS    06/02/2014         55
...       ...             ...
```

Now I need to merge Data1 with Data2 and **only keep the Target data with a (-1, +1) trading day window**. The final output will look like this:

```
RIC  Trading_day_window     date           price
VOD         -1            01/02/2014         50
VOD          0            03/02/2014         57
VOD         +1            05/02/2014         64
BATS        -1            01/02/2014         70
BATS         0            03/02/2014         58
BATS        +1            05/02/2014         67
```

I know I have to use `merge` here first. But how to **only keep the Target data with a (-1, +1) trading day window?**

I think I might use `subquery` here. 
Can anyone help me out ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use a double DOW loop.  In the first one find the record where the dates match. In the second one output the records you want.

Here is your sample data, properly sorted.

```
data data1 ;
  input RIC $ date ;
  informat date ddmmyy10.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
BATS 03/02/2014
VOD 03/02/2014
;;;;
data data2;
  input RIC $ date price ;
  informat date ddmmyy10.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
BATS 01/02/2014 70
BATS 03/02/2014 58
BATS 05/02/2014 67
BATS 06/02/2014 55
VOD 01/02/2014 50
VOD 03/02/2014 57
VOD 05/02/2014 64
VOD 06/02/2014 58
VOD 08/02/2014 64
VOD 10/02/2014 57
;;;;
```

Now just merge by RIC and DATE and find the matching records.

```
data want ;
  do trading_day=1 by 1 until (last.ric);
    merge data1 (in=in1) data2;
    by ric date;
    if in1 then baseday = trading_day;
  end;
  do trading_day=1 by 1 until (last.ric);
    merge data1 (in=in1) data2;
    by ric date;
    if baseday -1 <= trading_day <= baseday+1 then do;
         trading_day_window = trading_day-baseday;
         output;
    end;
  end;
run;
proc print; run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [retain](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm) statement in your data step.

Comment: thanks, I used `retain` before, but can you give me more information ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple `proc sql` statement can do this, using the `between` statement in the join.  I've coded +/- 2 days as that seems to be the case in your example data, you can obviously make adjustments to this to comply with whatever rule you use to calculate trading window.

```
data data1;
input RIC $ date :ddmmyy10.;
format date date9.;
datalines; 
VOD     03/02/2014
BATS    03/02/2014
;
run;

data data2;
input RIC $ date :ddmmyy10. price;
format date date9.;
datalines;
VOD     01/02/2014         50
VOD     03/02/2014         57
VOD     05/02/2014         64
VOD     06/02/2014         58
VOD     08/02/2014         64
VOD     10/02/2014         57
BATS    01/02/2014         70
BATS    03/02/2014         58
BATS    05/02/2014         67
BATS    06/02/2014         55
;
run;

proc sql;
create table want 
as select 
    b.ric,
    b.date-a.date as trading_day_window,
    b.date,
    b.price
from data1 as a
     inner join
     data2 as b
     on a.ric=b.ric 
     and b.date between a.date-2 and a.date+2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some good answers here, so you'll have to play with it to pick the most efficient.

I'm suspecting that your data1 is pretty small. If it is, then I think this will be pretty efficient code as it avoids the sorting and potential sql optimizer malarchy. Otherwise, the SQL solution seems the most practical to me.

```
proc sql noprint;
select count(*)
into :OBSCOUNT
from data1;
quit;

data want(drop=date_ref ric_ref);
set data2;
   do   i = 1 to &obscount.;
    set data1 (rename=(date=date_ref ric=ric_ref)) point=i;
    trading_day_window = (abs(date-date_ref)-1)*sign(date-date_ref);
    if ric=ric_ref
        and -1 <= trading_day_window <= 1
    then output;
   end;
run;
```